# Counting qualitative values based on the date range in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am learning to use Pandas library and need to perform analysis and plot the crime data set below. Each row represents one occurrence of crime. date_rep column contains daily dates for a year.

[image]

Data needs to be grouped by month and instances of specific crime need to be added up per month, like in the table below.

[image]

The problem I am running into is that data in crime column is qualitative and I just cant find resources online that can help me solve this!

I have been reading up on groupby and different methods of sorting but what is the most efficient way of accomplishing this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replicate something of your data:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date_rep':pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=100),
    ...:                    'crm_cd_desc':np.random.choice(['robbery', 'traffic', 'assault'], size=100)})


In [30]: df.head()
Out[30]: 
  crm_cd_desc   date_rep
0     traffic 2012-01-01
1     traffic 2012-01-02
2     assault 2012-01-03
3     robbery 2012-01-04
```

In essence, what you want to do is a **value counts**:

```
In [31]: df['crm_cd_desc'].value_counts()
Out[31]: 
assault    36
traffic    34
robbery    30
dtype: int64
```

However, you want to do this for each month seperately. To group by month, you can use `pd.Grouper` inside `groupby` to specify the month:

```
In [34]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_rep', freq='M'))['crm_cd_desc'].value_counts()
Out[34]: 
date_rep           
2012-01-31  traffic    12
            robbery    10
            assault     9
2012-02-29  assault    13
            traffic    11
            robbery     5
2012-03-31  assault    12
            robbery    10
            traffic     9
2012-04-30  robbery     5
            assault     2
            traffic     2
dtype: int64
```

And then `unstack` to get the result:

```
In [35]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_rep', freq='M'))['crm_cd_desc'].value_counts().unstack()
Out[35]: 
            assault  robbery  traffic
date_rep                             
2012-01-31        9       10       12
2012-02-29       13        5       11
2012-03-31       12       10        9
2012-04-30        2        5        2
```

Instead of using `value_counts`, you can also group by both the month and the crime type and then calculate the length of each group:

```
In [46]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date_rep', freq='M'), 'crm_cd_desc']).size().unstack()
Out[46]: 
crm_cd_desc  assault  robbery  traffic
date_rep                              
2012-01-31        9       10       12
2012-02-29       13        5       11
2012-03-31       12       10        9
2012-04-30        2        5        2
```

Comment: This is great! It appears that it is sorted by day. Do you know how to group this by month instead of by day?

Comment: What do you mean with 'sorted by day'? It *is* grouped by month, only are the months represented by the last day of that month .. If you want that the index shows `2012-01` instead of `2012-01-31`, you can convert the DatetimeIndex to a PeriodIndex with `df = df.to_period()`