# Get the daily percentages of values that fall within certain ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset of test results where I have a columns to represent the date a test was completed and number of hours it took to complete the test i.e.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Completed':['21/03/2020','22/03/2020','21/03/2020','24/03/2020','24/03/2020',], 'Hours_taken':[23,32,8,73,41]})
```

I have a months worth of test data and the tests can take anywhere from a couple of hours to a couple of days. I want to try and work out, for each day, what percentage of tests fall within the ranges of 24hrs/48hrs/72hrs ect. to complete, up to the percentage of tests that took longer than a week.

I've been able to work it out generally without taking the dates into account like so:

```
Lab_tests['one-day'] = Lab_tests['hours'].between(0,24)
Lab_tests['two-day'] = Lab_tests['hours'].between(24,48)
Lab_tests['GreaterThanWeek'] = Lab_tests['hours'] >168

one = Lab_tests['1-day'].value_counts().loc[True]
two = Lab_tests['two-day'].value_counts().loc[True]
eight = Lab_tests['GreaterThanWeek'].value_counts().loc[True]

print(one/10407 * 100)
print(two/10407 * 100)
print(eight/10407 * 100)
```

Ideally I'd like to represent the percentages in another dataset where the rows represent the dates and the columns represent the data ranges. But I can't work out how to take what I've done and modify it to get these percentages for each date. Is this possible to do in pandas?

This question, [Counting qualitative values based on the date range in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321357/counting-qualitative-values-based-on-the-date-range-in-pandas) is quite similar but the fact that I'm counting the occurrences in specified ranges is throwing me off and I haven't been able to get a solution out of it.

Bonus Question

I'm sure you've noticed my current code is not the most elegant thing in the world, is the a cleaner way to do what I've done above, as I'm doing that for every data range that I want?

**Edit:**
So the Output for the sample data given would look like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1-day':[100,0,0,0], '2-day':[0,100,0,50],'3-day':[0,0,0,0],'4-day':[0,0,0,50]},index=['21/03/2020','22/03/2020','23/03/2020','24/03/2020'])
```

Comment: Can you add expected DataFrame from sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to do a few final steps:

First, cast your `bools` to `ints`, so that you can sum them.

```
Lab_tests['one-day'] = Lab_tests['hours'].between(0,24).astype(int)
Lab_tests['two-day'] = Lab_tests['hours'].between(24,48).astype(int)
Lab_tests['GreaterThanWeek'] = (Lab_tests['hours'] > 168).astype(int)

    Completed  hours  one-day  two-day  GreaterThanWeek
0  21/03/2020     23        1        0                0
1  22/03/2020     32        0        1                0
2  21/03/2020      8        1        0                0
3  24/03/2020     73        0        0                0
4  24/03/2020     41        0        1                0
```

Then, drop the `hours` column and roll the rest up to the level of `Completed`:

```
Lab_tests['one-day'] = Lab_tests['hours'].between(0,24).astype(int)
Lab_tests['two-day'] = Lab_tests['hours'].between(24,48).astype(int)
Lab_tests['GreaterThanWeek'] = (Lab_tests['hours'] > 168).astype(int)

Lab_tests.drop('hours', axis=1).groupby('Completed').sum()

            one-day  two-day  GreaterThanWeek
Completed                                    
21/03/2020        2        0                0
22/03/2020        0        1                0
24/03/2020        0        1                0
```

**EDIT:** To get to percent, you just need to divide each column by the sum of all three. You can sum columns by defining the `axis` of the sum:

```
...
daily_totals = Lab_tests.drop('hours', axis=1).groupby('Completed').sum()
daily_totals.sum(axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                           

Completed
21/03/2020    2
22/03/2020    1
24/03/2020    1
dtype: int64
```

Then divide the daily totals dataframe by the column-wise sum of the daily totals (again, we use `axis` to define whether each value of the series will be the divisor for a row or a column.):

```
daily_totals.div(daily_totals.sum(axis=1), axis=0)                                                                                                                                           

            one-day  two-day  GreaterThanWeek
Completed                                    
21/03/2020      1.0      0.0              0.0
22/03/2020      0.0      1.0              0.0
24/03/2020      0.0      1.0              0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple in the end! Would have any ideas on turning that final output into percentages for the days? Would creating a new column containing the sum of each row and then dividing that back into each column of the row be my best bet?

Comment: Happy to help! I added some help to get to percent.